# How to merge two different borders in curses

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

Using curses for python, how can I seamlessly merge two borders? For example:

```
import curses

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
screen.border()
screen.refresh()

awindow =  curses.newwin(3, curses.COLS, 0, 0)
awindow.border()
awindow.refresh()

while True:
    curses.noecho()
    c = screen.getch(1, 1)
    if c == ord('q') or c == ord('Q'):
        break

curses.endwin()
```

this creates two windows, but in the two points where the borders meet there's a discontinuity. How can I remove that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by overwriting those gaps with `ACS_LTEE` and `ACS_RTEE` characters.  The python curses reference section *For more information* points you to the ncurses manual pages, saying

> If you’re in doubt about the detailed behavior of the curses functions, consult the manual pages for your curses implementation, whether it’s ncurses or a proprietary Unix vendor’s. The manual pages will document any quirks, and provide complete lists of all the functions, attributes, and ***`ACS_*`*** characters available to you.

In this case, the information is in the [`addch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Line-Graphics) manual page.

Comment: If I just add `screen.addch(2, 0, curses.ACS_LTEE)` and `screen.addch(2, curses.COLS - 1, curses.ACS_RTEE)` one of the two horizontal lines disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example draws the borders in a different window (not "screen"): `awindow.border()`, and you should make the fixes in that window.

Comment: The line `awindow.addch(2, curses.COLS - 1, curses.ACS_RTEE)` gives me the error `awindow.addch(2, curses.COLS - 1, curses.ACS_RTEE)_curses.error: addch() returned ERR`.

Comment: You'll have to catch/ignore the exception from writing to the lower-right corner of a curses window (there's a question/answer for [**that**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921946/write-an-utf8-character-to-the-last-position-of-the-screen-with-python-curses/41923640#41923640)).

Comment: Thanks. Simply replacing `addch` with `insch` worked for me.